# Understanding javascript object instance or work flow

Tags: javascript, object

can anyone explain what the following JavaScript object means or how it works:

```js
var var1 = (function(){
    // some code
  })();

var1(function(){
    // some code
  })
```

Comment: The code as given has been edited too much and is meaningless. In particular, the content of the first `// some code` matters quite a lot, in particular whatever it is it returns (presumably a function, but...).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first snippet of code executes the function inside the brackets right away and sets var1 to the function's return value.

ASSUMING THAT the return value of the first snippet is itself a function, the second snippet of code will call that function with the result of the second function passed as a parameter.......

Comment: "The function in the first snippet" NOT "returns a function", but the return value of a function, as you wrote in the line before.
Sorry for my fussiness, but "instance issue" is very important to understand how javascript works.

Answer (score 0):

This first expression will create an anonymous function expression that gets invoked immediately, and assign its *return value* to the variable `var1`.

[see this post](http://benalman.com/news/2010/11/immediately-invoked-function-expression/)

The second expression is calling a function named `var1` and passing a function result as the argument. In your sample code, `var1` is the result of an immediately invoked function so it would error out because the result is not a function.